# Flatten array of nested objects

Tags: javascript

I have data like so:

```
data = [
  {
    "foo": {"name":"foo-name"},
    "bar": {"name":"bar-name"}
  },
  {
    "baz": {"name":"baz-name"}
  }
]
```

and my desired output would be:

```
[
  { "foo": {"name":"foo-name"}},
  { "bar": {"name":"bar-name"}},
  { "baz": {"name":"baz-name"}}
]
```

How do I get this structure? I tried using `concat`, but realized that it doesn't work as we are dealing with nested objects and not nested arrays. Then I tried iterating in different ways, but not achieving what I want. One try was the following:

```
const newData = data.map((x) => {
  return Object.keys(x).map(el => {
    return {[el]: x};
  })
})
```

But that just made it more nested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap#Browser_compatibility)

```js
let data = [{"foo": {"name":"foo-name"},"bar": {"name":"bar-name"}},{"baz": {"name":"baz-name"}}]

let final = data.flatMap(a => Object.entries(a).map(([k, v]) => ({
  [k]: v
})))

console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 3):

One option is to `reduce` into an array, iterating over the entries of each object and pushing them to the accumulator:

```js
const data = [
  {
    "foo": {"name":"foo-name"},
    "bar": {"name":"bar-name"}
  },
  {
    "baz": {"name":"baz-name"}
  }
];

const output = data.reduce((a, obj) => {
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, val]) => {
    a.push({ [key]: val });
  });
  return a;
}, []);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thank you, upvote! Code maniac answer was the neatest in my opinion, so the accepted vote went there, but thanks for you anwer!

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a simple `for-of` with `Object.entries` mapped to objects:

```
const result = [];
for (const obj of data) {
    result.push(
        ...Object.entries(obj).map(
            ([key, value]) => ({[key]: value})
        )
    );
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const data = [
  {
    "foo": {"name":"foo-name"},
    "bar": {"name":"bar-name"}
  },
  {
    "baz": {"name":"baz-name"}
  }
];
const result = [];
for (const obj of data) {
    result.push(
        ...Object.entries(obj).map(
            ([key, value]) => ({[key]: value})
        )
    );
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: On side note: can we use `concat` instead of `push` so we will  need not to spread explicitly

Comment: @CodeManiac - `concat` will create a new array, so the code would create new arrays all over the place. That's why I used `push`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder oh yeah makes sense, maybe a off topic question, since JS have GC does this affect much creating a new array every time vs pushing values to the same array everytime ?

Comment: @CodeManiac - Creates memory pressure, which *can* be a source of performance issues. But of course, it depends on whether this code is run one-off or lots. Odds are pretty high that it wouldn't matter. Also note that the above *in theory* involves creating an object (the iterator) in order to spread out the array for `push`, so it would seem to be a zero-sum equation (create array or create iterator) -- except that JavaScript engines optimize away that iterator when they can (as above). If I were really concerned and didn't know that, I'd use `result.push.apply(result, /*...*/)` instead. :-D

Comment: This `push` solution is also only valid for arrays up to about 30k entries. (I'm assuming the OP's object doesn't have more than 30k properties.) After which, you run out of stack on V8.